# Slow Apache response

Tags: performance, apache, ddos

I have a high performance softlayer server. I am only running a (php-based. It's not an IRC server) chat room on this server. It works all fine. On average server response (for chat room) is 100MS with 100+ concurrent users. Some days ago a user threat to ddos our server. Now the server is so slow. On average ping time is 1500-2000MS with just 50-60 users. There is no high resource usage or bandwidth usage. I did following things to protect my server:

```
1 - DDOS protection (softlayer providers it)
2 - Install mod qos and evassive for appache
3 - Disabled ping of death and Syn packets
```

I performed following analysis:

```
1 - Analyzed apache logs. There isn't any frequent request from same IP or CLRF packets.
2 - Not many UDP packets 
3 - Checked connections per IP and they are all normal.
```

However, nothing is working. That user threats and kills our time whenever he says/wants. Is there any other thing I should look into to protect my server? What kind of attack he could make to do this?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is going to be they are exhausting your apache workers (usually a default of 150), you might want to check to see how many apache threads are currently running, and if its ~150 that might be why you have slow response times.

Some good reading on apache performance tuning.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html

http://www.monitis.com/blog/2011/07/05/25-apache-performance-tuning-tips/

https://www.devside.net/articles/apache-performance-tuning

The output from the following commands might also be useful in figuring out whats going on.

See whats running

```
ps auxf
```

See what apache is doing by turning on server-status (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html)

```
apachectl fullstatus
```

See whats going on with network connections

```
netstat -npl
```

Anyway, I hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! You have solved a long searched problem I had.